# How to sort an array alphabetically if integers are concatenated with array values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, quicksort

I have an array like this

```
$array = [
  125 => '3110 - with a string',
  128 => '3009 - keep a string',
  126 => '3111 - a string',
  121 => '3114 - be a string',
  122 => '3113 - last string',
]
```

Is there any way to use the PHP default sort functions to sort this array alphabetically and ignoring the concatenated integer values?

The result should be

```
[
  126 => '3111 - a string',
  121 => '3114 - be a string',
  128 => '3009 - keep a string',
  122 => '3113 - last string',
  125 => '3110 - with a string', 
]
```

I tried with sort and asort functions but it did not help.

```
asort($array, SORT_STRING);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please add your code efforts

Comment: is it necessary to use default sort functions, because I don't think you will get default functions to help your case here

Comment: I tried with the php `sort` function and `asort` `asort($array, SORT_STRING);`

Comment: you can  use usort() and a preg_split

Comment: <?php
$array = [
  125 => '3110 - with a string',
  128 => '3009 - keep a string',
  126 => '3111 - a string',
  121 => '3114 - be a string',
  122 => '3113 - last string',
];
function cmp($a, $b) {
 $text1 = preg_split("/- /", "$a");
 $text2 = preg_split("/- /", "$b");
 return strcmp( $text1[1],  $text2[1]);
}

usort($array, "cmp");

 var_export($array);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort()` along with `strcmp()`

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    
    return strcmp(trim(explode('-',$a)[1]) ,trim(explode('-',$b)[1]));
}


usort($array, "cmp");

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/NEdmt

Assumption : I assume that each values of array always contain digit - string format